# Is a ASP.NET MVC controller action faster/more efficient than a HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, httphandler, controller-action

I'm trying to create a simple lightweight server side redirect which inspects the client's User-Agent and redirects to a website for a given browser.  For example:

```
if(Request.UserAgent.contains("Firefox") { //redirect to www.yahoo.com }
else if(Request.UserAgent.contains("Safari") { //redirect to www.google.com }
else { // redirect to www.msn.com }
```

What would be the most performant/efficient way of accomplishing this using asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Controllers implement IHttpHandler behind the scenes and use reflection to execute action methods.

Comment: Any suggestions as to the most performant means of accomplishing the server side redirect?

Comment: Implement the IHttpHandler interface in an ".ashx" file and use Response.Redirect inside. Set the IsReusable property to return true.